# Reduce Self joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following tables

```
create table temp1(id int, value1 varchar(20), value2 varchar(20),value3 varchar(20))
insert into temp1 values (100,'apple','orange','mango')
insert into temp1 values(101,'banana','grapes','mango')
insert into temp1 values(102,'litchi','grapes','apple')

create table temp2(id int, value varchar(20))
insert into temp2 values(100,'banana')
insert into temp2 values(100,'grapes')
insert into temp2 values(100,'apple')
insert into temp2 values(101,'banana')
insert into temp2 values(101,'litchi')
insert into temp2 values(102,'mango')
insert into temp2 values(102,'orange')
insert into temp2 values(102,'banana')
```

Now, the following query joins value1,value2,value3 columns from temp1 with value column in temp2 and id from both tables:

```
select t1.id,t2.value value1,t3.value value2,t4.value value3 from temp1 t1
left join
temp2 t2 on (t1.value1=t2.value) and (t1.id = t2.id)
left join
temp2 t3 on (t1.value2=t3.value) and (t1.id = t3.id)
left join
temp2 t4 on (t1.value3=t4.value) and (t1.id = t4.id)
```

Output

```
    id  value1  value2  value3
1   100 apple   NULL    NULL
2   101 banana  NULL    NULL
3   102 NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Is there a way to rewrite the query so that I don't have to join temp1 with temp2 3 times? Actually temp2 is a table with lots of rows, so don't want to hit it 3 times. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question is bit of mess.. need clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OR statements in the join. I've updated this to handle the value2 and value3 fields:

```
select  t1.id
        , case
            when t1.value1=t2.value then t2.value
            else null
        end as value1
        , case
            when t1.value2=t2.value then t2.value
            else null
        end as value2
        , case
            when t1.value3=t2.value then t2.value
            else null
        end as value3
from temp1 t1
left join
temp2 t2 on ((t1.value1=t2.value) and (t1.id = t2.id))
            OR ((t1.value2=t2.value) and (t1.id = t2.id))
            OR ((t1.value3=t2.value) and (t1.id = t2.id))
```

Comment: Columns value2 and value3 will have values. In this case it's NULL, however I want to display both value2 and value3 (From temp2) in the output.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't follow the logic originally. I've updated the answer so it will return the values I think you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**`UNPIVOT-JOIN-PIVOT`** This technique can filter a crosstab without resorting to manipulating all the columns individually.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT t1.id,t1.col,t2.value
  FROM temp1
  UNPIVOT(value FOR col IN (value1,value2,value3)) t1
  LEFT JOIN temp2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id and t1.value = t2.value
) t3
PIVOT(MAX(value) FOR col IN (value1,value2,value3)) t4
```